# How to write a test case for a function inside another?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, mean

I have a js file (index.js) like below

```
  function index() {
   sum(a,b) {
      return a+b;
   };

   test() {
     ---
     ---
   }

  };
```

In my test.js file (Using jest)

```
  const index = require('./index');
  console.log(index)
  test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
     expect(index.sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
  });
```

It throwing error 
    TypeError: index.sum is not a function

Comment: If `sum()` is defined inside `index()` it is part of `index()`'s implementation, not a separate testable unit. You should be testing that the result of `index` is correct. If `sum` should be a separate, testable until, it should be available outside `index()` -- either by defining outside `index` or returning it from `index`.

Answer (score 1):

a good practice could always be - split the functions, do not nest functions, that way it is accessible and reusable.

if you have tried to create a Class or export a specific function then -

you can read here about classes in js - https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

and you can read here about exporting with require - 
https://www.openmymind.net/2012/2/3/Node-Require-and-Exports/

```
module.exports.sum = sum;
```

should solve you're problems probably (as long as sum is exposed to the outer scope)